# I have an error in vscode when trying to install flame under pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to install flame but whenever I run the pub get it gives me a really long error "Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on xml 3.6.1 and tiled >=0.4.0 depends on xml ^4.2.0,  flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with tiled >=0.4.0."  And then under it is a version solving failed error message.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at C:\Users\marci\Downloads\flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (7 days ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\marci\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\marci\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.1

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

```
name: ggg
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

  flame: ^0.24.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Can you provide the `pubspec.yaml` file, and also result from running `flutter doctor -v` inside your terminal?

Comment: @hisam I just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem today and checked on the Flame Discord channel.

They told me they have a conflict with their lib with stable flutter channel.

Recommendation is to change to Flutter Channel Beta.

I did that, then did Flutter Upgrade, then finally Flutter Pub Get and it worked.

Terminal Commands

To check which channel you are currently on

```
Flutter Channel
```

To change to the beta channel

```
Flutter Channel Beta
```

To get the beta version

```
Flutter Upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going crazy trying to fix it.  Now I can finally work!

Comment: Ya, i hear you.  I've been going somewhat nutty trying to learn Dart, Flutter and now Flame.  Starting to get the hang of it.  Thier Discord channel has been a blessing.

Answer (score 0):

So, when I have the same problem with you when I tried it.

Here's my solution:

In your `dependencies:` section inside the `pubspec.yaml` file, change the `flame` section without any version tag:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

  flame:
```